# Where to place the parse.initialize()

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm currently building an app with a small team on both iOS and Android, though right now I'm only focussing on Android. On their website tutorial they say the following line fairly early.

Before continuing, select your Parse app from the menu at the right. These steps are for your "NameAppHere" app.

Call Parse.initialize from the onCreate method of your Application class to set your application id and client key:

```
public void onCreate() {
  Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
}
```

They say I have to paste that bit of code in the onCreate method of the Application class, though there isn't an 'Application' class or Application.java. I already copied their .jar file into the project structure through one of the menu options Android studio gives me. I specified before this walkthrough that I already have an existing project, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create your own custom Application class by creating a class that extends Application and then override onCreate (just like you would any activity) and place that line in.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
    }
}
```

You also have to tell the manifest that you are using a custome application class. You can do this by, in your AndroidManifest.xml file, you will have to set the name element to the location of you new Application class:

```
<application
        android:name="com.packageName.example.MyApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher_no_text" >
```

Comment: Mmhmm thanks, I did that, though now I have another error, he doesn't recognize the Parse class. I suspect I didn't import the .jar file correctly, though I did so with one of the Android Studio menu options, so I have no clue why that'd be wrong.

Comment: You have to put the jar in in \libs and then right click on the jar and select the option "import library" (or something similar to that).  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Well I've now pasted the .jar file in the app/libs folder and apparently that works fine. Parse classes are now found, so I'm guessing that's okay right now. Though thanks anyway!

Comment: Right, that is what I meant. Sorry for the confusion. I am glad you got it working!

Comment: they should really put this step into the "quick start" tutorial

Comment: hi @Andre Perkins can we initialize master key like this

Answer (score 1):

You should create class and extend it to `Application`

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
     public void onCreate() {
      Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
      //...Rest of the Parse initializations.
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, just create a new class like that, nothing else, except if they refer to it in the tutorial?

Comment: That's what they refer in the tutorial. You could also put it in your activity but that will work only for THAT activity.

Comment: Ah okay, didn't quite understand that then. Thanks! I made a new class for that, since there'll be quite a lot of activities.

Answer (score 0):

It always exists, but if you want to modify it, you can extend the `Application` class.

There's a tutorial over here explaining how: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

The official Google Android docs on this topic can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).